# Выравнивание блока относительно родителя

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как "прибить" блок поиска к правому краю `ul` и выровнять его по вертикали? А в "схлопнутом" варианте сделать его под остальными `li`.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(91, 91, 91);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.Shape_1 {
  margin-top: 3%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0.38;
  width: 259px;
  height: 29px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
 <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="Shape_1"> поиск    
    </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для соответственного `li`

```
li {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```